# NoMethodError in Pins#index - undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting `undefined method 'image' for nil:NilClass` in the **index.html.haml** page of my app.

However on the **show.html.haml** page the code works fine and the image renders perfectly.

I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcnfFS_DS8 and it works perfectly for him. Check it at 48:16.
I've gone through it several times but I still can't figure out what I'm missing.

Here is the error:

> Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/pins/index.html.haml where
>   line #2 raised:
>
> undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass
>
> Extracted source (around line #2):

```
1 - @pins.each do |pin|
2     = link_to (image_tag @pin.image.url(:medium)), pin
3     %h2= link_to pin.title, pin
```

---

Here is my code:

**index.html.haml**

```
- @pins.each do |pin|
    = link_to (image_tag @pin.image.url(:medium)), pin
    %h2= link_to pin.title, pin
```

---

**show.html.haml**

```
= image_tag @pin.image.url(:medium)
%h1= @pin.title
%p= @pin.description
%p
    Submitted by
    = @pin.user.email
```

---

**pins_controller.rb**

```
before_action :find_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
    @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC")
end

def show
end

private

def pin_params
   params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :description, :image) 
end

def find_pin
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
end
```

---

**pin.rb**

```
belongs_to :user

has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300#"}
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

---

I managed to fix other NoMethodErrors but I can't figure out why I'm getting this one. It would be really great if someone could explain why I'm getting this specific error.

Comment: this line has error `= link_to (image_tag @pin.image.url(:medium)), pin` cahnge it to `= link_to (image_tag pin.image.url(:medium)), pin`

Comment: You're using `@pin` in the `each` loop, not the local `pin` variable ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thanks, I guess your comment explains why this works in the show page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the comments.

@Sontya wrote:

this line has error

```
= link_to (image_tag @pin.image.url(:medium)), pin
```

change it to

```
= link_to (image_tag pin.image.url(:medium)), pin
```